# How do you display timeouts when using ping6 on macOS?

Tags: macos, ping, ipv6, icmp

When using `ping6` (IPv6 version of ping), on macOS, I don't visually see the request timeouts when they occur.  The ping responses just pause for each request that times out.

A super observant eye will notice the seq number skips at 777.  Which is the only hint that a timeout occurred.

```
16 bytes from 2607:f8b0:4009:801::200e, icmp_seq=775 hlim=56 time=24.166 ms
16 bytes from 2607:f8b0:4009:801::200e, icmp_seq=776 hlim=56 time=26.226 ms
16 bytes from 2607:f8b0:4009:801::200e, icmp_seq=778 hlim=56 time=24.981 ms
16 bytes from 2607:f8b0:4009:801::200e, icmp_seq=779 hlim=56 time=25.807 ms
16 bytes from 2607:f8b0:4009:801::200e, icmp_seq=780 hlim=56 time=25.149 ms
```

I can run `ping6 -R` which will give me an audible sound for each request that times out, but that's not nearly as useful as seeing the typical `Request timeout for icmp_seq 123`.  This is especially true when running multiple pings at once in various terminal windows.

`man ping6` doesn't offer any obvious solution here either.

**How do I get the ping responses to look like this?**

```
16 bytes from 2607:f8b0:4009:801::200e, icmp_seq=775 hlim=56 time=24.166 ms
16 bytes from 2607:f8b0:4009:801::200e, icmp_seq=776 hlim=56 time=26.226 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 777
16 bytes from 2607:f8b0:4009:801::200e, icmp_seq=778 hlim=56 time=24.981 ms
16 bytes from 2607:f8b0:4009:801::200e, icmp_seq=779 hlim=56 time=25.807 ms
16 bytes from 2607:f8b0:4009:801::200e, icmp_seq=780 hlim=56 time=25.149 ms
```

Comment: You could install the GNU ping6 and see if it does what you need. It's part of GNU's "inetutils" package, so if you already use Homebrew, it's just `brew install inetutils`. By default it'll be installed as `gping6` to not conflict with the system ping6, but brew's install output tells you how you can add a directory to your PATH to have it show up as your default `ping6`.

Comment: good suggestion.  I tried `gping6` but it too didn't display the timeouts either sadly.  (side note, `gping6` has to be run with sudo to work properly)

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if the fact neither shows timeouts isn't a coincidence.